# checking for empty argument in meta-command

Tags: macros, hyperref, conditionals

In a current work, i'm using tons of CURIEs (shortened URIs), as common in  my community. So i defined a meta-command called `\defcurie` that i can use to define a prefix like `\defcurie{dbr}{http://dbpedia.org/resource/}`. It will create a command `\dbr` in this case that i can later use like `\dbr{Dog}` to print (and correctly link) [dbr:Dog](http://dbpedia.org/resource/Dog).

Currently when just using `\dbr{}` it prints [dbr:](http://dbpedia.org/resource/), but i'd like to make it print just [dbr](http://dbpedia.org/resource/) (without the trailing `:`) in case the arg is empty.

#### MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\curiesize}{\small}
\newcommand{\defcurie}[2]{%
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname#1\endcsname[1]{{\curiesize \href{#2##1}{\nolinkurl{#1:##1}}}}%
}
\defcurie{dbr}{http://dbpedia.org/resource/}
\begin{document}
Normal: \dbr{Dog}

Empty: \dbr{}

\end{document}
```

[image: current output]

As you can see in the second line there's a final `:` that i want to get rid of.

I obviously already tried various things like (each line one attempt, i'll spare you the `\noexpand` and `\expandafter` permutations that i ended up trying out of despair):

```
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname#1\endcsname[1]{{\curiesize \href{#2##1}{\nolinkurl{#1\IfStrEq{##1}{}{}{:##1}}}}}%
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname#1\endcsname[1]{{\curiesize \href{#2##1}{\nolinkurl{#1\ifthenelse{\isempty{##1}}{}{:##1}}}}}%
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname#1\endcsname[1]{{\curiesize \href{#2##1}{\nolinkurl{#1\IfValueT{##1}{:##1}}}}}%
```

Anything obvious i'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `\ifblank` from `etoolbox` in order to check the argument `##1` of the internally defined macro.

Alternative: Use `\notblank` and switch the order of `True/False` branch

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\curiesize}{\small}
\newcommand{\defcurie}[2]{%
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname#1\endcsname[1]{{\curiesize \href{#2##1}{\nolinkurl{#1\ifblank{##1}{}{:##1}}}}}%
}
\defcurie{dbr}{http://dbpedia.org/resource/}
\begin{document}
Normal: \dbr{Dog}

Empty: \dbr{}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess this is the preferable answer. I slightly modified the original answer by pulling the `\ifblank` back to reduce code-dup. (Tested to work).

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\curiesize}{\small}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\MyIfEmptyF}[1]{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax%
    \expandafter\@gobble%
  \else%
    \expandafter\@firstofone%
  \fi}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\defcurie}[2]{%
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname#1\endcsname[1]{{\curiesize
    \href{#2##1}{\nolinkurl{#1\MyIfEmptyF{##1}{:##1}}}}}%
}
\defcurie{dbr}{http://dbpedia.org/resource/}
\begin{document}
Normal: \dbr{Dog}

Empty: \dbr{}

\end{document}
```